# Alternative way to activate keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

I have three keyboard layouts: English, Russian and Greek. I use first two very often, and the Greek is only needed when working on some statistical problems (from time to time). My preferred way to switch layouts is Alt+Shift. But I always need to cycle through Greek layout even when I don't really need it. Is there a way to switch between English and Russian with Alt+Shift, and to activate Greek with some other way? I'm on Linux Mint 20 Ulyana MATE (which is similar to Ubuntu Focal).